# When deploying DotNet core apps on Linux, what is the base/programdata directory to store logs and settings file?

Tags: c#, linux, .net-core

In Windows, I normally store settings, logs, and etc in the 'C:\ProgramData\MyApp' directory.
This is accessed via:

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData)
```

I'm learning how to develop Linux apps now. In Linux where is the equivalent of ProgramData directory to store settings?

Comment: Settings in /etc/<program-name> and logs in /var/log/<program-name>.

Comment: some are saying the /usr/folder

Comment: in newer *nix is CommonApplicationData set to /usr/share   (in my case Ubuntu 22)